Issues Managing Python Environments on macOS
I'm experiencing some difficulties managing Python environments on my Mac, and I could use some guidance. Here are the details of my current setup:

I previously used Miniconda for various open-source software and scripting, but I have since cleanly uninstalled it.
I have Homebrew installed, which is essential for my workflow. However, when I need to install ffmpeg, it seems to pull in a version of Python from Homebrew.
Additionally, I have the default version of Python that comes pre-installed with macOS.

Given this setup, I'm struggling to keep my Python environments organized and avoid conflicts between different installations.
Recently, I've encountered an issue with the ok autograder while working on Lab 0: Getting Started. When I run the command:
python3 ok -q python-basics -u
I receive the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'

How can I resolve the ModuleNotFoundError related to urllib3?
What is the best practice for managing multiple Python environments on macOS to avoid such issues in the future?
Are there any tools or strategies you recommend for maintaining a clean and efficient Python environment on macOS?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
I’ve been looking for tutorials on environment managers like conda and venv, but as a beginner programmer, I’m not sure which one to choose. I used venv to create an isolated environment for a project, but I'm still unclear about why it’s necessary. This topic is really confusing for me.
I've checked the version of the urllib3 (urllib3==1.25.7, suitable for ok), but I'm not sure it's on which one of my pythons.

Obligatory XKCD

In my opinion just use Pyenv  set its python to global and use it everywhere , for different python version install them using pyenv, set them to   global/local level accordingly

This is a common problem, and you might find it helpful to read the top answer on What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc? .
My personal preference is to use pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv together, so that I can have multiple versions of python installed (because I work on different systems that are compatible with different versions of python) and also have different packages installed in the different versions. I am then diligent about creating virtual environments for each project that I work on, and install packages as needed for that specific project.
As to the version of Python installed via Homebrew, I aim to avoid installing any packages into it. Then, Homebrew can update it without breaking any dependencies.
